# Convert date in XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath

I was wondering how can you this kind of date into a normal one.

Sample xml:

[image]

I want my output to be like this: 01/03/1959 based from the sample xml. I'm using xslt version 1.0 and xpath 1.0

Comment: Please post your code as *code*, not as picture.

Comment: You may regard MM/DD/YYYY as "normal" but in most of the world it's considered a quaint local US peculiarity, rather like Fahrenheit and feet and inches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are no dates as such in XSLT 1.0, so just threat this as an exercise in string manipulation and write out:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(data, 5, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(data, 7, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(data, 1, 4)"/>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(data, 5, 2), '/', substring(data, 7, 2), '/', substring(data, 1, 4))"/>
```

---

> how can you this kind of date into a normal one.

Actually, the "normal one" would look like this: `1959-01-03`.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601